# Use a alias or generated number to connect to another IP

Tags: php, html, database, dns

How do I use an alias or masking number to connect to another IP?

**For example:**

192.168.0.1 is A's ip. Now I want to generate an alias suppose 1234. When I will type 1234 on my server then my server will check the db and connect the IP behind the alias or masking number then connect and ping with 192.168.0.1.

Comment: It doesn't seem like he speaks english naturally. It could be that he is asking how to code the connection in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 'alias' with the name you generate. This is just a MySQL example of how you would connect. Setting the alias would be a DNS entry (on the internal DNS server, or externally with your hosting provider.)

```
<?php
 $link = mysql_connect('alias:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
 if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo 'Connected successfully';
 mysql_close($link);
 ?>
```

We really cant help with DNS unless we know what provider you are using, or whether you are creating entries on a internal DNS server (in which case we need to know your OS)